# Microsoft Bot Framework - Handoff to an agent

Tags: botframework

I am working on creating a chat bot using microsoft bot framework. Have a requirement to add an agent into the conversation if the bot is not able to identify customer's intent.

All the examples that I found are for botbuilder:3.7.0 but we are using botbuilder:4.1.5 .

Found a method in BotFrameworkAdapter, which would help us do this but it is not working.

```
reference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);

await adapter.createConversation(reference, async (ctx) => {
                        console.log(ctx);
                        await ctx.sendActivity("Hi (in private) -- Successful ");
                    });
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at this repo - [https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample)

Comment: Thanks @tdurnford! But I am using node SDK, can you help me with a node example?

Comment: I've created a human handoff example in Node on my GitHub. You can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/tdurnford/botframework-human-handoff). Please let me know if you have any comments or questions.